# Loosing DataContext focus when set second DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have class `TabItemView.xaml.cs` with constructor. I'm setting in it `DataContext` to `MainViewModel` because in TabItemView located DataGrid to wich I need to bind data.

```
public partial class TabItemView : UserControl
{
    public TabItemView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainViewModel myModel= new MainViewModel();
            this.DataContext = myModel;
        }
    }
```

In class `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I also set `DataContext` to the `MainViewModel` in the button_Click event. This event adds new Tab on button click

```
 public partial class MainWindow2 : Window
    {
     //Constructor and some other stuf
                 .....
  private void AddInvoice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        string s = string.Format("Tab {0}", count);
        mainViewModel.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel(s));
        this.DataContext = mainViewModel;
    }
}
```

This is my `MainViewModel`

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> invoice_items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Invoice_Items
    {
        get
        {
            return invoice_items;
        }
        set
        {
            invoice_items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Invoice_Items");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    private int _selectedTabIndex;

public int SelectedTabIndex
{
    get { return _selectedTabIndex; }
    set { _selectedTabIndex = value; }
}

public MainViewModel()
{
    SelectedTabIndex = 0;
}


}
```

}

This is markup for `MainWindow`

```
Grid>
            <TabControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabName}"><TextBlock.Background><SolidColorBrush /></TextBlock.Background></TextBlock>
                            <Button Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0"  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}" BorderBrush="#00000000">
                                <Image Source="/WPF_AccApp;component/Images/11.gif" Height="11" Width="11"></Image>
                            </Button>
                            <DockPanel.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush />
                            </DockPanel.Background>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:TabItemView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
```

And this is for `TabItemView`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF_AccApp.Views.TabItemView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="640" d:DesignWidth="800" Focusable="True" IsHitTestVisible="True">
    <Grid Name="grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="768" MinHeight="446" Focusable="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="43" Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="45" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="45" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="350" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Supplier}" Grid.Column="1" Height="27" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="11,6,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="141" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" DataContext="{Binding}" />
        <Label Content="Supplier" Height="27" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="21,6,0,0" Width="Auto" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Black" Background="White" MinWidth="133" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SupplierBank}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="14" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="11,6,0,0" Name="textBox11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" MinWidth="141" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Supplier Bank" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" Margin="21,6,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Background="White" MinWidth="133" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SupplierAccount}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="14" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="11,6,0,0" Name="textBox12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" MinWidth="141" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="Account Number" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" Margin="21,6,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" MinWidth="133" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Buyer}" Grid.Column="4" FontSize="14" Height="27" Margin="11,6,20,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" MinWidth="141" />
        <Label Grid.Column="3" Content="Buyer" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" Margin="21,6,0,0" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" MinWidth="133" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding BuyerBank}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="14" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="11,6,20,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" MinWidth="141" />
        <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Content="Buyer Bank" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" Margin="21,6,0,0" Name="label6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" MinWidth="133" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding BuyerAccount}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="14" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="11,6,20,0" Name="textBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" MinWidth="141" />
        <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Content="Account Number" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" Margin="21,6,0,0" Name="label7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" MinWidth="133" />
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="3" 
              Height="104" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="55,115,55,0" Name="dataGrid1" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" CanUserResizeRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Invoice_Items}"
              IsReadOnly="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name" Binding="{Binding Item_Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mesure" Binding="{Binding Mesure, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price exc VAT" Binding="{Binding Price_exc_VAT, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="VAT" Binding="{Binding VAT, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price Inc VAT" Binding="{Binding Price_inc_VAT, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Binding="{Binding Total, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="3" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="textBox5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Margin="11,0,0,0" />
    <Label Background="White" Content="Shipping Address" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" Margin="21,0,0,0" MinWidth="133" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="3" />
    <Label Background="White" Content="Invoice #" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="27" Margin="78,65,0,0" MinWidth="133" Name="label8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Now the problem. When I'm setting DataContext only in `MainWindow` my `TextBoxes` are reacting normaly and my `ObservableCollection` Items is notified about changes. When I add new Tab it creates normaly with no text in `TextBoxes`.

But, when I set DataContext in both `MainWindow` and `TabItemView` (like in code which I added) to notify my Invoice_Item `ObservableCollection` about changes in `DataGrid` my DataContext for both `ObservableCollection`'s are lost, they are no longer notified about changes. When I add new Tab it dublicates data that I added in previous Tabs in both `TextBox`s and `DataGrid`.

Also when I don't set DataContext in `MainWindow` and set it only in `TabItemView` my `ObservableCollection` Invoice_Items becomes notified about changes in `DataGrid`, but when I add new Tab, `DataGrid`'s data just dublicates in each added Tab.

Why is this happening, what I'm doing wrong? And how can I fix this issues?
If you need more code or info just say. I'm looking for any help in understanding how to solve my problem. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: `DataGrid's` data just dublicates in each added Tab. because you are setting same instance of ViewModel to each tab which has the collection.

Comment: >> when I set DataContext in both MainWindow and TabItemView,
Where do you set `DataContext` for `TabItemView`.

Comment: In TabItemView constructor...